# ActiveX Textbox, search for entered value

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have an ActiveX Text box linked to Cell D1.

I want to use this to search for any value that is entered into the text box.

However, if i wanted to search for `Peter` as soon as i type in `P` it begins the search, and does not let me finish typing `eter`

I want to be able to type, and then press ENTER to find the value.

This is what i have got to:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Dim findval As String

findval = Range("D1").Value

    Cells.Find(What:=findval, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What about a button next to the search bar to execute the search order?  Or a `keyup` event which listens specifically for the Enter key? A `Change` event gets executed at every key press, not ideal for what you want.

Comment: yeah i had thought about adding a search button that will just search for the vlaue in D1 once entered via the text box, was hoping there would be way of doing it without the box though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be wiser to use a `KeyUp` event, specifically for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Dim findval As String
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        findval = Range("D1").Value

        Cells.Find(What:=findval, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.